# Replacing alphanumeric string in R

Tags: r, string, replace, stringr

I have a dataset with alphanumeric strings. I am trying to replace the numeric part of the string with "nnnn" and the alphabet part with "aaaa". The length of the alphabet and numeric part does not matter.

| Example: | What I am expecting |
| --- | --- |
| #100001032218888example1 | #nnnnaaaannnn |
| #1-example-2 | #nnnn-aaaa-nnnn |

I tried this:

```
  mutate(str_alpha = str_replace_all(col_name, "\\w+", "aaaa"),
         str_num_alpha = str_replace_all(str_alpha, "\\d+", "nnnn"))
```

I think I got the "\\w+" incorrect because it replaces the numeric part of the string too.

Can someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the reverse i.e. replace first the alphabets and then the digits so

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(str_replace_all(str1, "[[:alpha:]]+", "aaaa"), "\\d+", "nnnn")
```

-output

```
[1] "#nnnnaaaannnn"   "#nnnn-aaaa-nnnn"
```

---

Or using a named vector in a single `str_replace_all`

```
str_replace_all(str1, setNames(c("aaaa", "nnnn"), c("[[:alpha:]]+", "\\d+")))
[1] "#nnnnaaaannnn"   "#nnnn-aaaa-nnnn"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("#100001032218888example1", "#1-example-2")
```